# Will there be re-enter issue with the following twisted code?

Tags: python, twisted, deferred

I'm learning Twisted recently, and just now I re-read some basic docs on Deferred, here is some example code from:http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.3.0/core/howto/defer.html

What about commenting out the second `g = Getter()` out? 
Will there be re-enter poblem? Do you have some good ideas on how to avoid these kind of issue?

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer

class Getter:
    def gotResults(self, x):
        """
        The Deferred mechanism provides a mechanism to signal error
        conditions.  In this case, odd numbers are bad.

        This function demonstrates a more complex way of starting
        the callback chain by checking for expected results and
        choosing whether to fire the callback or errback chain
        """
        if self.d is None:
            print "Nowhere to put results"
            return

        d = self.d
        self.d = None
        if x % 2 == 0:
            d.callback(x*3)
        else:
            d.errback(ValueError("You used an odd number!"))

    def _toHTML(self, r):
        """
        This function converts r to HTML.

        It is added to the callback chain by getDummyData in
        order to demonstrate how a callback passes its own result
        to the next callback
        """
        return "Result: %s" % r

    def getDummyData(self, x):
        """
        The Deferred mechanism allows for chained callbacks.
        In this example, the output of gotResults is first
        passed through _toHTML on its way to printData.

        Again this function is a dummy, simulating a delayed result
        using callLater, rather than using a real asynchronous
        setup.
        """
        self.d = defer.Deferred()
        # simulate a delayed result by asking the reactor to schedule
        # gotResults in 2 seconds time
        reactor.callLater(2, self.gotResults, x)
        self.d.addCallback(self._toHTML)
        return self.d

def printData(d):
    print d

def printError(failure):
    import sys
    sys.stderr.write(str(failure))

# this series of callbacks and errbacks will print an error message
g = Getter()
d = g.getDummyData(3)
d.addCallback(printData)
d.addErrback(printError)

# this series of callbacks and errbacks will print "Result: 12"
#g = Getter() #<= What about commenting this line out? 
d = g.getDummyData(4)
d.addCallback(printData)
d.addErrback(printError)

reactor.callLater(4, reactor.stop)
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you comment the second `g = Getter()`, you will have a problem.  The same `Deferred` will fire twice because you have the `Deferred` stored in the `Getter` object.  In particular, the second call to `getDummyData` will overwrite the first `Deferred`.

You shouldn't do this.  As a general point, I don't think it is a good idea to hold onto `Deferred` objects, because they can only fire once and it is all too easy to have a problem like you do.

What you should do is this:

```
def getDummyData(self, x):
    ...
    d = defer.Deferred()
    # simulate a delayed result by asking the reactor to schedule
    # gotResults in 2 seconds time
    reactor.callLater(2, self.gotResults, x, d)
    d.addCallback(self._toHTML)
    return d
```

And:

```
def gotResults(self, x, d):
    """
    The Deferred mechanism provides a mechanism to signal error
    conditions.  In this case, odd numbers are bad.

    This function demonstrates a more complex way of starting
    the callback chain by checking for expected results and
    choosing whether to fire the callback or errback chain
    """
    if d is None:
        print "Nowhere to put results"
        return

    if x % 2 == 0:
        d.callback(x*3)
    else:
        d.errback(ValueError("You used an odd number!"))
```

Notice that in this case `Getter` has no state, which is good, and you don't need a class for it!

My opinioin is that `Deferred`s should be used to give the **caller** of your function the ability to do something with the result when it becomes available.  They should **not** be used for anything fancier.  So, I always have

```
def func():
    d = defer.Deferred()
    ...
    return d
```

If the caller has to hold on to the `Deferred` for whatever reason, they may, but I can freely call `func` multiple times without having to worry about hidden state.

Comment: Totally agree with you, `Getter` should not have state, You just prevent me from making a same problem in another piece of code, Thanks!